# React native webview show website in logged in state

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

I am new to react native and first time using the react-native-webview. We already have website build using wordpress now I tried the develop the app for the website.

My issue was when I try to open the URL in webview it asking the credentials to login the page. but I have already login in the mobile, now I tried to open any website URL in webview it again asking the credentials to login.

I have searched in google since weeks but I don't have any clue.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue or sent the login credentials to webview and open the URL.

```
 <>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={isLoading} />
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://.....',
        }}
        onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(false)}
      />
    </>
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I too am currently implementing such functionality.

Comment: Yess Ratchet .Use this code  <>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={isLoading} />
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://.....', headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }}
        onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(false)}
      />
    </> and then you need to set the cookie from backend .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution :
Use this code

```js
<ActivityIndicator visible={isLoading} />
  <WebView
    source={{
      uri: 'https://.....', 
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }}
    onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(false)}
  />
```

and then you need to set the cookie from backend.